# scrollTop has a default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger a `button` with `ID = clicktv` onscroll down, also i want to set scrolltop of the document to 0 after triggering it.

Everything works great, but i can't scroll down the document after it. How can I set scrolltop of a document to 0 then after that, it will turn to default to be able to scroll it down again.

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).scroll( function() {
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(top != 0){

            $("#clicktv").click();

        }
    });

    $("#clicktv").click(function(){
        $(document).scrollTop(1);
        $("#head").animate({"margin-top": "-680px"},1200);
        $("#nav1").animate({"margin-top": "900px"},1200);
        $("#nav1 a").css("color","#a65400");
    })

})
```

Comment: I guess you cant scroll down because `$("#clicktv").click();` gets fired everytime you try to scroll.

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking of that, but how can I set scrolltop to 0 then after that it will return to default??? Any ways for further details of what am I asking, just visit this link: http://tympanus.net/Development/ArticleIntroEffects/index6.html,